# Please I need help, how can I solve this heat impulsive system?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations, heat-equation

Please I need your help!!
I need to solve the following system:

$$
    \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \partial_{t} \psi(x,t)-\Delta \psi(x,t)=0, & (x,t)\in (0,1) \times((0, 2) \backslash\{1\}) \\
    \psi(0,t)= \psi(1,t)=0, & t \in  (0, 2) \\
    \psi(x, 0)= x (1-x), & x \in (0,1) \\
    \psi(x, 1)=\psi\left(x, 1^{-}\right)+4, & x \in (0,1)
    \end{array}\right.
    $$

$1^{-}$  denotes the limit to the left!

Best regards,

Comment: What is $\Delta\psi(x,t)$? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: if $x$ goes from zero to 1 and $t$ from 0 to 2, why does the last condition says $x$ from 0 to 2? You can easily solve the above heat PDE without the last condition you have, which I do not understand what physically it means. Here is the code 
`pde=D[u[x,t],t]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
bc={u[0,t]==0,u[1,t]==0};
ic=u[x,0]==x*(1-x);
sol=DSolve[{pde,ic,bc},u[x,t],{x,t}]`

Comment: @thorimur it must be the Laplacian but in 1D, where only $x$ is the spatial coordinate.

Comment: Sorry for the last condition it was a mistake, $x \in (0,1)$, I just correct it. but I need to solve this system with the last condition. This phenomenon has a sense physically, it call's impulsive. In the first line, x goes from 0 to 1, and t goes from 0 to 2 except 1. what happen in 1 is exactly the last condition (impulsion).  Best regards,

Comment: This really isn't a forum for getting homework coded by others.

Comment: – Daniel Lichtblau , if you think it's that easy try to do it (challenge)! this is a system for research paper and not homework as you said.

Comment: Show the code you have tried in Mathematica format (not an image of the code)  and the results you obtained.

Comment: It's best to explain why a question is downvoted (although I did not cast the downvote myself). The _impression_ this question makes is that someone heard that Mathematica can solve differential equations, but that person does not know how to use Mathematica, so asks others to do it. This is considered inappropriate on this site. It is something you would pay a consultant to do. The expectations is that first you learn the basics of Mathematica, learn how to solve _simple_ differential equations, then explain what specific difficulty you encountered while trying to solve your actual one.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what you want. Mathematica 12.3 solves it in several minutes:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] == 
    D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + DiracDelta[t - 1], u[0, t] == 0, 
   u[1, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == x (1 - x)}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Result is returned an two inactive sums:

```
FullSimplify[sol /. K[1] -> n, t ∈ Reals]

Inactive[Sum][-((4 (-1 + (-1)^n) E^(-n^2 π^2 t) Sin[n π x])/(n^3 π^3)), {n, 1, ∞}] + 
 Inactive[Sum][-((2 (-1 + (-1)^n) E^(-n^2 π^2 (-1 + t))
     HeavisideTheta[-1 + t] Sin[n π x])/(n π)), {n, 1, ∞}]
```